# NextJs - Link to scroll to a section in same page

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I'm using NextJs. I would like to create a link in my header section. This link should take the user to TestimonialsSection on the same page by scrolling.

```
        <Link href={"#TestimonialsSection"}>
          <a className={styles.Designation}>Mentor</a>
        </Link>
```

This is the code I tried, but it didn't work. The URL changes though. Thanks in advance

Comment: You need to set `id` of you testimonials section to `"TestimonialsSection"` to make this work.

Comment: The Id is set, but it doesn't work

Comment: Could you please provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)?

Answer (score 64, accepted):

In vanilla HTML you'd do something like this

```
<a href="#first-section">My first section</a>
<a href="#second-section">My second section</a>

<div id="first-section">SECTION 1</div>
<main id="second-section">SECTION 2</main>
```

In NextJS you'd so something similar. Instead of using the anchor tag for linking, you'd use the `Link` components.

```
<Link href="#first-section">My first section</Link>
<Link href="#second-section">My second section</Link>

<div id="first-section">SECTION 1</div>
<main id="second-section">SECTION 2</main>
```

This would work just fine.
However, if you want your starting URL to be `www.my-site.com/#second-section`, you would need to set the Link component's `scroll` prop to `false`.
Ex:

```
...
<Link href="#second-section" scroll={false}>My second section</Link>
...
```

Make sure your sections/divs ie the target elements have the **ID** attribute set to them properly without the `#` and the corresponding
anchor links have the `#` prefixed to **ID** name

Here's the official NextJS documentation https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next/link

Hope this resolves your issue.

Comment: In the official documentation scroll={false} don’t mention anything about url. It basically says don’t scroll to the top of the page which is a default behaviour.

Comment: hey @omerS, the hash/id segmented scrolling was at the end of the page. Here's a [link](https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next/link#disable-scrolling-to-the-top-of-the-page) to it

Comment: that is what I was trying to say too. I am confused about your url comment. :D

Comment: When you add # to URL it signifies some ID of that page. And Next link does that easily. If you have a link eg `https://www.example.com#section-1` and the example.com homepage has a section with id of section-1 it will scroll to that part using next/link. Is it not working for you somehow?

Comment: okay got it, everything is clear now. I was just confused about that part in your answer, it is all good now. thanks

Comment: this answer does not work i nextjs13

Answer (score 7):

Give a try this solution, I'm using TypeScript so this answer will definetly work with TypeScript Next.js

```
export default function Home() {

  // let's make a function that receive the specific element_id as string and scroll into that element_id
  const scrolltoHash = function (element_id: string) {
    const element = document.getElementById(element_id)
    element?.scrollIntoView({ behavior: "smooth", block: "end", inline: "nearest" });
  }


  return (
    <div>

      {/* attach that function with onClick event to an clickable element */}
      <div onClick={() => scrolltoHash('contact')}>
        <span>Click me to Scroll</span>
      </div>

      {/* ...imagine lot of sections/code here */}


      <section id="contact">
        {/* this is the section we want to scroll it could be any element not just limited to section but must have an unique ID. */}
      </section>

      
      
      {/* ...imagine lot of sections/code here */}

    </div>
  )
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If it's just a static string you should remove the braces as ЖнецЪ says above.

If you're making a reusable component where you need to specify the ID from a parent, use a template string and keep the braces.

```
<Link href={`#${props.id}`}>
  <a className={styles.Designation}>Mentor</a>
</Link>
```

Answer (score 2):

Let say we are navigate to the footer:

```html
<footer id='footer'>
 ...
</footer>
```

1. import the Link component:

```js
import Link from 'next/link';
```

2. Call Link component with `href='#your id'` and `scroll={false}`

```
<Link href='#footer' scroll={false} />
```

Scroll to the top of the page after a navigation. Defaults to true

Answer (score 1):

`<Link>` to an element on the same page is not working as expected in some versions of Next (like Next 13.4.2), as described by this issue : https://github.com/vercel/next.js/issues/44295.

Also as described there, replacing `<Link>` by native `<a>` works fine

Answer (score 0):

Try to use Link tag and in URL add #some-link and then in Link tag href with href='#some-link'

[www.google.com/#some-link](http://www.google.com/#some-link)

```
<Link href='#some-link'>
    // code section
</Link>
```

Answer (score 0):

try using the react-scroll

```
import { Link } from "react-scroll/modules"
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this Like in Header we have different options.

```
<Link href="/home#mysection>My Section <Link />
```

if we want to go `/about` or from about to that specific part we can easily jump to specific part like here mysection

```
MySection.jsx
    <div id="mysection">
          My Section
    </div>
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! It seems like this has already been suggested in other answers. When answering a question, try to look through the answers already there and see if there are any duplicates. I do hope you'll stick around!