# NextJs 13: Link to scroll to a section

Tags: next.js

I want to link different sections on a single page. I already saw [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68589788/nextjs-link-to-scroll-to-a-section-in-same-page), but it doesn't work for me. In the following I have created a demo that is as clear as possible for my two attempts:

**1st attempt:**

```
app/layout.tsx:

<Link href="#home" scroll={false}> Home </Link>
<Link href="#about" scroll={false}> About </Link>


app/page.tsx:

<section id="home" className="min-h-screen">home</section>
<section id="about" className="min-h-screen">about</section>
```

When i click a link in this attemp, I see the following error on my dev run in the browser:
[image: browser error of 1st attempt]

---

**2nd attempt:**

I added a slash to the links, to refer to the route of the home page

```
app/layout.tsx:

<Link href="/#home" scroll={false}> Home </Link>
<Link href="/#about" scroll={false}> About </Link>


app/page.tsx:

<section id="home" className="min-h-screen">home</section>
<section id="about" className="min-h-screen">about</section>
```

Now the browser jumps to the top of the page for both links, which is the home section. For the about link, it should of course also scroll to the appropriate section.

---

**EDIT 12/04/2022:**

It seems to be related to the link component of Next, because when I open the developer tools with F12 and click on the links in the a tags generated from the link components, scrolling to the individual sections works.

Comment: so the Link component in nextjs cannot act like useRef in React to jump to certain section on same page of react ?

Answer (score 1):

It is an issue with 13.1 as well, I am using 13.2.

I solved the in-page navigation for now with old  tags.
This is the quick-brute solution.
It is important to slash them if you have a MPA because it will add the #tag to the MPA's currently active slug and you can not navigate back once you changed page.

```
  <section key="navWrap" className={styles.navWrap}>
    <a key="services" href="/#">home</a>
    <a key="portfolio" href="/#portfolio">portfolio</a>
    <a key="contact" href="/#contact">contact</a>
    <a key="about" href="/#about">about</a>
    <Link key="blog" href="/blog">blog</Link>
  </section>
```

I kept Link for the multi page direction hoping the (pre rendering ect...) next features will remain be strong with this one.
Example for the SPA points {...}.

I am only using server components.

Answer (score 1):

I am also using 13.2.4 the same issue I faced
If you want to scroll on the different sections on the same page then you can use this approach.

It can be easily solved by using the traditional anchor tag of `<a href={"id"}>Home</a>`

In next js 13 the link tag is working only for multiple pages not for a single page.

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve smooth scrolling navigation in Next.js by using the scrollIntoView method and preventing the default behavior of anchor tags when clicking on a.

```
const handleScroll = (e) => {
e.preventDefault();

const href = e.currentTarget.href;
const targetId = href.replace(/.*\#/, "");

const elem = document.getElementById(targetId);
elem?.scrollIntoView({
  behavior: "smooth",
});`
```

`<a onClick={handleScroll} href={'#Gerichte'} className={styles.navLink}>GERICHTE</a>`

Answer (score 0):

remove this scroll={false}

app/layout.tsx:

```
<Link href="#home">Home</Link>
<Link href="#about"> About </Link>
```

app/page.tsx:

```
<section id="home" className="min-h-screen">home</section>
<section id="about" className="min-h-screen">about</section>
```