Navigation to a parallel route(slot) in a page in next js 14
parallel routes
I've been trying to navigate to a section of my project's home page. I have 3 parallel routes in the home page and a navigation bar on top that consists of links to other pages and links to sections in the home page (parallel routes in this case). Since there is no url route for these slots I'm seeking a way to access these slots through Link href.
I tried using id and #example but it gets pretty messy with urls like this:
http://localhost:3000/about#pricing
And such logic does not work cause it needs many conditions to handle 2 types of links (the ones with # and the normal page routes)

I don't think you should use parallel routes in your case, as it sounds overkill. I believe anchor tags are what you're looking for. Go take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/a/70745758/12931054 answer.
On the other hand, if you insist on the parallel routes (or if I'm misunderstanding something), please share how you implement the slotting on your codes.

@AndreHadianto Yes you are right. I switched back to using components instead of slots (keeping the # links for now)
